# ManytoMany related to django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

## modes.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Vendor(models.Model):
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bill_no = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

## serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class VendorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self, validate_data):
        product_data = validate_data.pop('product')
        vendor = Vendor.objects.create(**validate_data)
        for product_data in product_data:
            Product.objects.create(vendor=vendor, **product_data)
        return Vendor
```

## views.py

```
class VendorViewset(viewsets.ModelViewset):
      serializer_class = VendorSerializer
      queryset = Vendor.objects.all()
```

How should I write product view such that It can be demonstrated that products of certain vendor can only be viewed with url routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `@detail_route`:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route

class VendorViewset(viewsets.ModelViewset):
      serializer_class = VendorSerializer
      queryset = Vendor.objects.all()

    @detail_route(methods=['GET'])
    def products(request, pk=None):
        qs = self.get_object().product.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and then the vendor products will be available by

```
YOUCURRENT_PATH_TO_DETAIL_VENDOR/products
```

Comment: After adding above code: I get ->Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:  
products() got multiple values for argument 'pk'

Comment: show url do you try, i don't understand how do you catch the error